# How to read the current machine NTFS settings?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2008, filestream, ntfs

Before inserting filestream data I'd like to check the following NTFS settings:

1) 8.3 naming status (this is disabled by using  `fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1`)

2) last access status (this is disabled by using `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1`)

3) cluster size (this is set with `format F: /FS:NTFS /V:MyFILESTREAMContainer /A:64K`)

The filestream recomendation is to disable (1) and (2) and to set (3) at 64kb.

But before setting this I'd like to know the existing settings. How do I check this? Answer can be in Delphi but not necessarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the registry for points 1 and 2 (using xp_regread in SQL)

Number 3 is not essential but helps and has been SQL Server best practice for a decade or more. You'd have to use sp_OA% or a CLR function to read this in SQL.

Comment: sp_OA% require speical permissions and moreover as you say it is not essential, so as a first step I will just write in the documentation that it is desirable to have cluster size to 64k.

Comment: The registry might contain the value 2 for disable8dot3 status, which means to look inside the volume itself, but it isn't very clear how you're supposed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364935(VS.85).aspx) Windows API call returns the sector_per_cluster and bytes_per_sector values. I think this function should be in Windows unit.

Comment: That will read the settings on the client machine, which may be different from the server box